# Deploy power bi report server as a SaaS solution

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I was thinking of a possible power bi report server infrastructure deployed internally and shared with clients.

*To put it simple :* they access our report server, and thanks to their data they can see the dashboards we created internally.

That is to say using PBIRS as a software as a service model.

But different **challenges** are present :

- authentication?

Possible to authenticate customers if we use a combination of VPN + new records in our internal AD.

- access to customer's data ? **Main challenge ...**

The primary reason for everyone of using PBIRS is that we don't want cloud usage.

**Is there a way in such an infrastructure to connect our PBIRS internal server directly to an other customer's network on premises data sources ?**

*Use case is as follow :
e.g : Client -> connect to provider with VPN -> authenticate in AD with provided credentials -> connect to PBIRS*

*with : PBIRS on Network 1 -> connecting directly with Customer's data on Network 2*

Comment: Power BI report server is essentially an SSRS report server, presumably similar challenges for exposing to clients as with SSRS, could use similar architectures people have used for that?

Comment: Supportive ref. to @Rich's suggestion - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cliffgreen/2011/03/29/reporting-services-single-sign-on-sso-authentication-part-1/